VSCode - python unit test locations
I have a large python project - it contains multiple parts, and a number of local "modules" that I put in modules directory.
For each local module, I want to create a set of UNIT TESTs.
I specifically do not want ALL unit tests for the entire project in one flat directory. Instead, I would like to have them split across a few sub directories.
In ascii - I have this:
   +-- src <-- Main application source code
   +-- Modules
      + module1
      + module2
   + unit-tests  <-- This is the problem directory.
      + mod1-tests <-- Module 1 Tests.
      + mod2-tests <-- Module 2 Tests.
      + tracking-test <-- Testing for the tracking feature
      + tlm-tests <-- Testing for the telemetry module

The problem is - VSCODE - Unit Test - will ONLY allow me to choose 1 test directory, a top most directory, in my case 'unit-tests' has the Tests organized by subject area. My question is: How can make this scan recursively and/or organize the tests rather then a giant directory with hundreds of tests (it makes it hard to find things)

This question is similar to: Recursive unittest discover. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
